# Reading an embedded H2 database

Tags: java, python, database, h2

I am using a 3rd party application written in Java which uses a local embedded H2 database to store data.

I want to write a Python app to read this data, and possibly write it back. There are a lot of suggestions around about using the Postgress engine in SQLAlchemy to achieve this however what I gather from this is I would need to install some kind of server on the local machine. I'm getting stuck at this point. Is there away around this, to access it more like a file to run SQL queries against it locally.This would also aid packaging (when I get to that).

Comment: Do you want to access the database at the same time as the Java application is using it? If so, you may be in trouble, as [in the embedded connection mode, only one process can access the database at a time](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes).

Comment: If concurrent access is required, you could use the automatic mixed mode: http://h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode (there are other solutions). But I wonder what API you use from Python to access the H2 database?

Comment: No, I'm not concerned about reading or writing to it at the same time as the other app. Each app will have exclusive access.

Answer (score 1):

H2 supports using the PostgreSQL ODBC driver by acting like a PostgreSQL server.

You will need to start H2 in server mode.

You can read about it here:

http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#odbc_driver

http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=46456